# Is “Tear a piece out of somebody” a popular idiom to mean snatch an advantage from somebody?

Tags: idioms

I came across the phrase ‘*tear a piece out of*' Obama in the debate’ in the following statement in the article titled “Obama Math: Obama Math: 8.1 + 13,300 + 50 = 270” in New Yorker magazine (September 10):

“Of course, something could still happen to change the polling dynamics. Romney could *tear a piece out of Obama* in the debates; the tsunami of negative ads the Republicans are about to unleash could conceivably turn around some Obama-leaning states; there could be an “October surprise.” As of now, though, there is no sign of Romney getting the surge he needs.”

I guess ‘tear a piece out of” means to snatch an advantage out of, or take the lead to somebody (If my interpretation is wrong, please correct me), but I can’t find this phrase as an idiom in any of dictionaries at hand.

What does 'a piece' represent for? I mean 'a piece of' what? 
Is “tear a piece out of”somebody / something a popular idiom, or just a set of words?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are "tearing a piece out of: is their *flesh*, literally or figuratively. In figurative use it means to damage an opponent, to 'draw blood' (another similar figure of speech), or in short: to **wound**. It's a metaphor of tooth and claw.

Its [use is not exactly common, but neither is it rare](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%98tear%20a%20piece%20out%20of%27&sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22%E2%80%98tear%20a%20piece%20out%20of%20him%22&oq=%22%E2%80%98tear%20a%20piece%20out%20of%20him%22&gs_l=serp.3...51600.52154.2.52524.6.6.0.0.0.2.119.570.5j1.6.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.t9CP1Ta0o3k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6ddc2c03e308bb3b&biw=1280&bih=675).

Comment: Where I live, "tear a strip off sb" is more common. This [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tear+a+piece+out+of%2Ctear+a+strip+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests it is universal, and [this one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tear+a+piece+out+of%2C+tear+a+strip+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) that "tear a piece out of sb" is almost unused in British English.

Comment: @RoaringFish I find these differences fascinating - for my part, I've never heard the "strip" variation over here in the States. Regarding the Ngrams, I'm not certain they can differentiate between tearing a strip of *somebody* vs. *something*, alas.